# PHP Tagging - Recall the same script to update an array and query

Tags: php, jquery

I'm implementing a tagging system for my comics site.

The tagging function should:

- allow the user to **select** multiple tags and display their selected tags out, selected tags should filter the comics shown
- allow the user to **deselect** chosen tags, which would update their selected tags and update the returned comics

[image]

The part I'm having trouble with is in blue in the above image:

How can I make a call back to the same php script if a user chooses to delete a selected tag?

Thanks!

Comment: You could send a $_GET var to the script that says your action is to delete or add a tag, along with which tag they are deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're just pushing elements into the $_SESSION array under a known key, isn't it acceptable to just check if the element exists? something similar to

```
if(isset($_SESSION[$tag])) {
  unset($_SESSION[$tag]);
} else {
  $_SESSION[$tag] = 1;
}
```

to use it, just use `array_keys()`. No need to change the JS side.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you could do, is send an array of tags that are being manipulated. They might be being added or removed - doesn't matter.

**Javascript**

```
$.get("getTags.php", {tags:["tag1","tag2","tag3"]}, function(data) {
    //have PHP return an updated list of tags.
});
```

Then, you iterate the tags that were sent, and check if they existed already. If they existed, you remove them. Otherwise, you add them.

**PHP**

```
$tags = $_GET["tags"];

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (array_key_exists($tag, $_SESSION['tags'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['tags'][$tag]);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['tags'][$tag] = $tag;
    }
}

//Return your updated list of tags here.
```

You could then return an updated list of tags if you wanted, just to make sure that everything was in sync.

---

Another option would be to explicitly state what action you are performing, by sending an "action" parameter in the AJAX call:

**Javascript**

```
$.get("getTags.php", {action: "remove", tags: ["tag1"]}, function(data) {
     //Do whatever
}
```

Then, handle that case in your PHP:

**PHP**

```
$availableActions = array("add", "delete");
$action = $_GET['action'];

//Make sure it's a valid action
$action = array_key_exists($action, $availableActions) ? $action : "add"; //Set a default.

//Now handle each action
switch ($action) {
    case "add":
        //Do stuff.
        break;
    case "delete":
        //Do stuff.
        break;
    default:
 }
```

Comment: I think the 2nd suggestion would work better because I also need to update the query (which returns the images) with the new set of tags